# How to track data events for triggering popups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, popup

By data event, I mean something that's not a physical event like a click, but something like "when a user first earns his 100th point" in a social network rewards system. (Please let me know if there is a term that describes this)

I currently have a `users` table that has_many `medals`, which are icons that are earned whenever a user meets a medal's required point threshold.
I am using the [Activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) to track user points through the built in helper `reputation_for(:points)`.

In my view, I show

```
Medal.all.each do |medal|
  if @user.reputation_for(:points) >= medal.requirement
    image_tag(medal.icon)
  end
end
```

This works fine in showing what badges have been earned, but I want to buid in a one-time pop-up message that congratulates the user when he first earns a badge.

What do I need to do to "know" when a user first meets a badge threshold?

Sorry this is quite broad, but don't really know where to start. Do I need to create a second model that "tracks" a user's progress? If so, what would that model look like? Would appreciate it if you could point me to any relevant resources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a RoR specialist but wouldn't it be possible to add a boolean to your `user` model that will tell you that no badges have been earned yet ?

That way when you add the `medal.icon`, you can check if it's the first time (for this user) and show her a congratulation popup and flag that by changing the bollean's value.

Comment: Thanks @Yannick. I guess I'd have to have a boolean column for each type of badge, and keep track of whether or not a user has been awarded each kind. I'll see if I can implement this later this week, and let you know. Thanks!